# Cannot attach the file .mdf as database in multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two projects in solution 'SOL':  (net 4.6.1)

1. `Domain`: Class Library - Responsible for access to Db (EF), Entities, repository etc.
2. `MVCStore`: ASP.NET MVC app - uses `Domain` in reference to retrieve the data from the database.

Additional information:

- CodeFirst model was used
- LocalDb is used
- In `Domain` / `web.config` also in `MVCStore` / `web.config` no connection string is defined

**It works well**

I added an additional ASP.NET MVC project

3. `GuideMVC` with reference to `Domain`.

When I want to do any operation on repository from `Domain` proj, I get an error:

> Cannot attach the file '...MVCStore\AppData\SOL.Domain.Concrete.EFDbContext.mdf'.mdf' as database 'SOL.Domain.Concrete.EFDbContex'

**So it doesn't work**

I added the connection string explicitly to `MVCStore/web.config` (copied from Server Explorer in VS) and it works now.

But the question is: what would be the reason that second project needs connection string in this case?

I added also Test project (console application) to my solution

- added reference to `Domain`
- added EF from NutGet (the same I did for second MVC project)

This also works!! And also without connection string in `web.config`.

What did I do wrong in my second MVC project?

I read many answer to question regarding such an error but the presented solutions came out to deleting the database. I have filled my database with many records and I don't want to remove any database.

Answer (score 0):

try restore it first to you sql server, then try to generate you model from db

Comment: I treat my MVC projects as "users" of Domain class Library whihc was create din the past. I do not want to modify/ recreate database at all.